# how to display a string pattern using php loops

Tags: php

my question is how to display string as a pattern using php loops like, if the string is computer,on first iteration it will display "c" and then second iteration it will display like "co" and so on.My following code given below.please give a solution.

```
    <?php   
      $array = "computer";
        $count = strlen($array);

        for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++)
        { 
            echo $array[$i]."<br>";

        }
    ?>
output will print like this
c
co
com
comp
compu
```

Comment: `$input = 'computer'; echo implode('<br>',array_map(function($n) use ($input) {return substr($input,0,$n);},range(1,strlen($input))));` - damnit this isn't CodeGolf again...

Comment: "please give a solution" - *sigh*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = "computer";
$count = strlen($array);
for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++)
{ 
  echo substr($array,0,$i+1)."<br>";
}

$array = "computer";
$count = strlen($array)-1;
$out='';
for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++)
{
  $out .= $array[$i]; 
  echo $out."<br>";
}
```

Have a nice day :-)

Comment: @justOnUnderMillions.It works.can you please tell me how to print the same output without substring function

Comment: With nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr($array, 0, $i + 1)` instead of `$array[$i]`. Visit to: [PHP: substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) for more information.